# Can I avoid circular imports in Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

app/**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__ name __)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)  
from app import views, models
```

app/models.py:

```
from app import db  # I want to avoid this everywhere
```

I really don't like my submodules having a dependency on their parent. Also can the global package variables be avoided too? I want a more OO solution.

One alternative for app is to use Blueprints I think, but then I loose the route decorator. Also the same cannot be done for db with SQLAlchemy (or can it?).

Comment: refer [this link](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/structuring-flask-apps-a-how-to-for-those-coming-from-django/) for a great guide towards creating project structure for flask.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Take a look at this project: https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask
It's a great example for doing things the right way. Many of great Flask features are used: blueprints, [application factories](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/appfactories/) and more.

[Here](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/app.py#L26) is how they register extensions, such as SQLAlchemy Database:

```
# app/extensions.py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
...


# app/app.py
from app.extensions import db

def create_app(config_object=ProdConfig):
    app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])
    app.config.from_object(config_object)
    register_extensions(app)
    ...

def register_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    ...
```

Comment: Great, I think this is exactly what I was looking for. So basically defining these globals in another package gets rid of the need for a circular import? That really cleans up the mess.

Comment: Exactly. Every object has its place and it's all neatly working together.

Comment: It took me an embarrassingly long time to get Flask setup the way I wanted. This helped tremendously. Many thanks.

Comment: Guess it's the best practice

Answer (score 31):

Try use 3rd. We create exts.py file to instancing SQLAlchemy like this:

## exts.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_xxx import xxx

db = SQLAlchemy()
...
```

## run.py

```
from flask import Flask

from .exts import db, ...


def register_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app) 
    ... 


def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__ name __)
    app.config.from_object(config)

    register_extensions(app)

    return app

app = create_app(config)
```

## models.py

```
from .exts import db


class XXXModel(db.Model):
    pass
```

Comment: This answer is more complete in the code example than the accepted one. Crucial addition is that `app` is defined in the called python file and given the return value of `create_app()`

Comment: But where to write `db.create_all()`.

Comment: A flask project generator. Based on Flask + SQLAlchemy + marshmallow + webargs. https://github.com/TTWShell/hobbit-core

Comment: @ThunderPhoenix try Flask-Migrate.