# How to factor out database models from a flask application running on mod_wsgi

Tags: python-3.x, flask, apache2, flask-sqlalchemy, mod-wsgi

During testing on my local machine I successfully factored out my database models:

flaskapp.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)  
from models import db
```

models.py:

```
from __main__ import app  
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I'm now trying to deploy this flaskapp using `mod_wsgi` on an apache2 server. However, flaskapp.py is no longer running as `__main__`. Can you factor out models.py without creating a circular reference? Is there an equivalent to `from __main__ import app` when running using `mod_wsgi`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I avoid circular imports in Flask and SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909816/can-i-avoid-circular-imports-in-flask-and-sqlalchemy)